# Session vs User.Identity.Name to check the loggeduser name for ASP.net core application with windows authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, windows-authentication

I have to get the user id from my database to do most of the functions in my application. I have .net core 2.1 application with windows authentication enabled.

My question is which is efficient way, is it to  request `User.Identity.Name` to check the loggeduser name and get the user id (with db query) or get the username from `User.Identity.Name` for the first time, query the id and assign it to  session  and use the id to subsequent request.

```
User user = new User(xDbContext);

if ((HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("CurrentUserId") == null))
{
    loggedUserId = userPrivilege.GetUserId(User.Identity.Name);
    HttpContext.Session.SetInt32("CurrentUserId", loggedUserId);
}
else
{
    loggedUserId = HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("CurrentUserId").Value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking if you should:

1. Query your database every time you need the value, or
2. Query the database once and store the value in `Session` so you have it the next time you need it

Then the answer is: it depends. If your `Session` data is stored in a database on a different server, then it won't make a difference. If your database is running on the same server as your site, then it will make very little difference.

If your database is on a different server and `Session` is stored in memory, then it will be much faster to retrieve the value from `Session`.

If your `Session` data is stored in a database, then another option is to use [in-memory caching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory?view=aspnetcore-2.2). But that data will be shared across all sessions, so you would have to make sure that one person's data isn't accessed in someone else's request.

Comment: Thank you it make sense how you brought my question to clarity.  How can I avoid my above code to be repeated in every action method.

Comment: You can use middleware, which will run on each request before your action method does. There is an example of this in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52547588/1202807)