# How do access another singletone service from IStartSession StartSession method?

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-core-3.1

I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52533831/is-there-a-session-start-equivalent-in-net-core-mvc-2-1) question accepted answer to highjack session start.

However - when I intercept new session start, I cannot access other global services which contains data I need on every session start and user request.

On old ASP.NET MVC 5 project, I did everythin at Global.asax on Application_AcquireRequestState event.

I need to access service, that I have added at ConfigureServices in Startup.cs

```
            services.AddSingleton<LocalisedResources>(
            sp => new LocalisedResources(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out - there was nothing to do with sessions.

Answer was found in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56493071/net-core-inject-singleton-service-in-another-singleton-service) post and was simple.

Needed to add Required service when I added InistSession service.

```
            services
            .AddSingleton<IStartSession, InitSession>(serviceProvider =>
            new InitSession(serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<LocalisedResources>()));
```